# Can Derby be used with Phonegap?

Tags: cordova, derbyjs

Is it possible to package a derbyjs application with phonegap?
I simply have not found a single reference to anybody doing this, while meteor is a [different story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322723/can-meteor-be-used-with-phonegap), so naturally I'm curious why that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From version 0.6 (coming soon) you will be able to separate client-side and server-side of derby app. And you will be able to use client-side app in phonegap.

Answer (score 4):

It's partially possible to do on 0.5 version.
Check out [psirenny](https://github.com/psirenny) repositories for examples on [setting up Derby-Phonegap app](https://github.com/psirenny/derbygap). There are also a bunch of example apps made this way and a Passport authentication library for Derby with Phonegap support.

Answer (score 1):

I had an interest of that as well. You may look through this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/derbyjs/Hna5c_WRrc0 to clarify it.

Comment: Please add some question-related explanations in your answer. Refer to [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) for more information about how to better anwser questions here.