# meteor - phonegap using MeteorRider or "hijack DOM" approach

Tags: android, ajax, cordova, meteor

I've created a `meteor.js` app which I deploy to meteor hosting service.
I wanted also to make  it a mobile app, so I started looking for solutions and came across with this [Github repo](https://github.com/zeroasterisk/MeteorRider).

MeteorRider, the approach is straightforward, get your meteor app going, then take your phonegap app srating and then "hijack" the DOM using `jquery $.ajax` request,
so this is what I've done:

1. meteor app running on meteor hosting, created phonegap app using phonegap
2. create my-app changed the www folder as the docs mention
3. changed the meteorUrl, changed phonegap confix.xml origin access to my host.
4. run locally on emulator using phonegap local run android.

and nothing happens..

Maybe someone has tried this? Or know how to get this working. I hate `iframes` this is way. I don't use cordova-phonegap and similar.

Comment: i figured how to make it work, ill try to post a guide soon for users that got stuck like me.

Comment: Did you happen to come across this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322723/can-meteor-be-used-with-phonegap

Comment: yes i have read this post, but i'm actually using MeteorRider

Comment: I'm updating the docs now (dev branch atm), it should be a bit simpler, but please give me a review and let me know... 

https://github.com/zeroasterisk/MeteorRider/tree/dev/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Meteor with PhoneGap, but this is what I would do to narrow down where the problem is:

1. Ensure your site works on your device's Android browser (this is what PhoneGap uses inside of the native app).
2. Point the meteorUrl to a Meteor.js site you know works on your device's Android browser.
3. Point the meteorUrl to a MeteorRider site that works for other people (you may need to ask the MeteorRider author for this).
4. Ask the MeteorRider author for the most recent Meteor.js version that he has confirmed works with MeteorRider.  You may find that there was a change in Meteor.js that broke it.  For example, I could see the new standard [browser-policy](http://docs.meteor.com/#browserpolicy) causing a problem.

Hopefully this will help, or spark an idea of another way to investigate the problem.

Comment: as i said i figured it out, ill try to upload a video or a step by step guide for getting the two play togther. but thanks jrullmann.