# Mobile App Development in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

Which framework is best for to develop mobile app in Meteor.I am new to meteor.So please give me suggestions for to develop mobile app frameworks like jquery or is there any more frameworks for mobile app development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never personally developed a mobile application with Meteor but if I did, I would use [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/).

I found this awhile back which is where I would start ([meteor-phonegap](https://github.com/guaka/meteor-phonegap)), I believe this only has support for Android currently though. If you are interested in cross-platform I would take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13110083/1429262) SO answer.

Comment: Not only a android other mobiles also like windows,tabs etc.@Firo

Comment: @Venkat look at the last sentence. The last link is for cross-platform, as well as phonegap in general.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to PhoneGap you can also interact with your Meteor app via native mobile apps.  There are DDP libraries for each of the major platforms so your app can communicate with the server-side Meteor code.

To re-use the client-side code you can go full PhoneGap or if you don't need access to the native sensors and such you can also just use an embedded browser UI component like PhoneGap does but without bothering with the 'bridge' technology they provide.

Answer (score 0):

## Hi you can use React Native as client side and Meteor in Server Side.

#### What is React Native?

React Native is the next generation of React a Javascript code library developed by Facebook and Instagram, which was released on Github in 2013. Native app creation means writing apps for a specific operating system. React Native helps developers reuse code across the web and on mobile.

#### Why React Native?

Because this is node it is possible to use React Native with Meteor with the same package in npm. The second thing is React Native is Cross Platform that can build app into Android and IOS.

Sample App 
https://github.com/spencercarli/react-native-meteor-boilerplate 
https://github.com/meteor-factory/awesome-react-native-meteor 
https://github.com/spencercarli/meteor-todos-react-native 
https://github.com/spencercarli/meteor-react-native-authentication 
https://github.com/spencercarli/quick-meteor-react-native`

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/showcase.html