# Cordova and Meteor : Both web and Mobile App

Tags: cordova, meteor

I am looking to serve both my website and mobile app (android and ios) with the same meteor server.

Are there any package or sample project that I can get started with ?

Comment: careful how you phrase these questions,  its legit to ask how to achieve what you want, asking for a sample project/package is not legit, its considered offtopic, which someone already has voted for

Comment: here at Meteor Development Group we are working on the built-in Cordova integration for Meteor. Stay tuned :) Also checkout the community solutions mentioned in answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:

- Three integration options [Meteor + PhoneGap/Cordova (Roundup – Fall 2013)](http://zeroasterisk.com/2013/08/22/meteor-phonegapcordova-roundup-fall-2013/):
- iOS/Web app Ralph Chat: [Open Sourcing Ralph](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/4xY54ZK4uCE)
- Cordova/Meteor relating repositories on github: [SpaceCapsule](https://github.com/SpaceCapsule)
- Blonk app: [Blonk: Building “Tinder for Jobs” with Meteor for Mobile](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/blonk-building-tinder-for-jobs-with-meteor-for-mobile/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a definitive answer, but I can point you to the following resources:

- Nice demo of Verso and how it's built: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eeY1mZhvDy4 (an iPhone app built by Tim Colman and his team)
- Project to help you deploy your app as an android app: https://github.com/guaka/meteor-phonegap
- Meteor package that provides support for mobile hardware support via Cordova Phonegap: https://github.com/awatson1978/cordova-phonegap

Related questions:

- [Can Meteor be used with PhoneGap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322723/can-meteor-be-used-with-phonegap)
- http://www.quora.com/Meteor-web-framework/I-want-to-build-an-app-for-iOS-with-Meteor-using-PhoneGap-What-should-be-some-of-my-next-steps
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/wxBfhJw0oVk