# Meteor JS on Windows, support for iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, windows, meteor

I am wondering if the Windows version of Meteor JS supports developing and running iOS and/or Android apps.

I am  hoping it at least supports Android.

Answer (score 11):

Februar 2016 - it now works with Version 1.3-cordova-beta.5.

You manually have to install

- [jdk (Java)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)
- [android sdk](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html)

Try the release by running `meteor update --release 1.3-cordova-beta.5` in your app directory.
Afterwards `meteor run android-device` works just fine

see some more details here
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6050

Comment: Hi, i've done it but when i try meteor run android-device with some server it says "Please add the Android platform to your project first." .

Comment: You still have to run `meteor add-platform android` beforehand.

See official tutorial here
https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/running-on-mobile

Answer (score 2):

From today it now supports Android, https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6050
It got developed by [Sedouard](https://github.com/sedouard) and included inside Meteor 1.3 beta release

Answer (score 1):

I just attempted to use the instructions [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/How-to-submit-your-Android-app-to-Play-Store) on windows and it told me.

```
 This command is not yet available on windows.
```

You can follow @snez's advice from this question here.
 [Can Meteor be used with PhoneGap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322723/can-meteor-be-used-with-phonegap)

You could try to experiment with the tutorial version which seems to work in mobile.

```
 meteor create --example localmarket
```

Answer (score 1):

In December 2015, the situation is still the same. I had a hard time today deploying my Meteor app on Android. I wrote down my findings, I hope it helps you too. It's here: https://geekycarrot.blogspot.com/2015/12/deploying-meteor-app-on-android.html

In a nutshell: It is possible to deploy for Windows, but it's tricky. You need a Linux operating system, at least in a virtual box. (Docker or Vagrant helps you with that. I recommend Docker.) You need to install an Android SDK on the Linux system. Building the app from the Linux console can be done by the steps I described. With a bit of creativity, the deployment process can be simplified to one click with a short Linux-side and a Windows-side script.

I have not found a solution for debugging though.

Answer (score 0):

I know it doesn't support iOS, but that is a limitation that the Apple sdk enforces (can only run the sdk on osx). I believe Android can run on Windows, but they haven't released it for Windows. See this link. https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Supported-Platforms

Comment: The link only describes running android on Linux and Mac. Will there soon be an official support of Android on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Meteor Windows still not support both Android or iOs yet, it will come soon.

Update news at Meteor roadmap here https://trello.com/c/ZMvnfMfI/11-official-windows-support

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-add-platform-android-please-heeeeeeeeeeelp/30296/7?u=nosizejosh) solves the add platform challenge on windows. It shows how you can get "meteor add-platform" working with meteor 1.3+ on windows.

Comment: Hi, a link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being *barely more than a link to an external site* is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)